# Bought activated Windows 8 Enterprise, need to reinstall, no product key

Tags: windows, windows-8

I bought a lightly used Lenovo Helix off the bay which came with an activated copy of Windows 8 Enterprise (not 8.1). Per the description, the laptop was used by a company to test an application and was no longer needed, thus it was sold to me. Unfortunately I did not receive an activation key with the purchase.

I need to wipe my hard drive and totally reinstall Windows. I would like to keep the Windows 8 Enterprise edition that came on the machine, even though the Windows Store tells me I cannot upgrade to 8.1.

I have two main problems:

1. I do not have and am unsure how to obtain the proper installation media
2. I do not have an activation key and I am not sure how to check if perhaps the key is burned into the BIOS (or however that works)

Using various "keyfinder" programs, I have learned that windows was installed from "Volume" media, and it reports that the key is "BBBBB-BBBBB-BBBBB-BBBBB-BBBBB", which is obviously not the real key. I'm assuming this was some sort of pre-activated enterprise style install.

So my question is, how can I proceed to do a complete reinstall of Windows 8 Enterprise Edition without having to purchase a new key?

(note: The seller will not respond to me.)

Comment: Unfourtunately, it was not within the sellers legal rights to sell you the computer with activated OEM licensed software on it. you are not eligidgealbe to use the OS as a second owner of the device, as that violates the license agreement. http://oem.microsoft.com/public/worldwide/refurb/microsoft_refurbished_pc_licensing_guidelines.pdf

Comment: @FrankThomas, this isn't an OEM license.

Comment: @FrankThomas, that doc is for "refurbished" pc's not private party sales.It does not apply to PC's sold by individuals.

Answer (score 0):

The Enterprise version of Windows is licensed totally differently to the consumer versions. As Frank says, they cannot transfer ownership of an Enterprise license as it will have been purchased as part of a bulk license deal, probably with EA rights. These are really subscription licenses.

You would have to buy an Enterprise subscription of some form. Your cheapest option is to purchase either a Microsoft Action Pack or an MSDN subscription. Both are annual costs but allow a limited number of enterprise licenses.

UPDATE: As Karan points out, your cheapest option is to purchase a copy of Windows 8.1 Std or Pro depending on the features you actually need. Checking Amazon.com I see that you can pick Pro up for around USD80 for a license code, the ISO images are available freely. The Microsoft Action Pack in constrast is around $500 per year & MSDN is typically more expensive. Though those will still be your cheapest option for getting Windows Enterprise if that is actually what you need.

Comment: "You would have to buy an Enterprise subscription of some form." - That is of course if Enterprise is even a requirement. If just Win8 Core/Pro will do that'll be far cheaper.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have covered that option too.